# How to remain specific data lines and delete others with oracle sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Table data like follows.

[image: table data picture]

I want to remain lines which timestamp are the biggest two for each IP, and others lines should be deleted.

Result should be:

```
192.168.1.1             1479250063
192.168.1.2             1479250068
```

How to implement it with oracle SQL?

Comment: Please post example data in question not as an image. Also `timestamp` is not good name for column.

Comment: Byt the way have you tried anything?

Comment: what did you try? please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such query will select top two rows for each ip:

```
select * from(
select ip, timestamp, row_number() over (partition by ip order by timestamp desc) r 
  from table) 
where r < 3;
```

Sometimes it is better to create table with new results and drop old table. If you really need to delete from your current table you can try:

```
delete from table where rowid not in (select rr from(
    select rowid rr, row_number() over (partition by ip order by timestamp desc) r 
      from table) 
    where r < 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!